# The more common pronunciation of "buoyancy"

Tags: pronunciation

Which is more common pronunciation of "buoyancy" in AmE?http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/buoyancy?q=buoyancy
In the dictionary above, there are two pronunciations. One  is /ˈbɔɪənsi/ and the other is /ˈbuːjənsi/. Which one is more common in AmE?

Comment: (AmE) To be honest, I can hardly tell the difference between the two. Although the first one does sound more natural to me.

Comment: In this case, "buoy" should be pronounced same as "boy". Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Bare *buoy* exhibits the same variation in pronunciation, /bɔɪ/ vs /ˈbuːi/.

Comment: Related at EL&U: *[The pronunciation of buoy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24318)*

Answer (score 1):

To me, I had to listen to them several times before I could tell the difference. It sounds more natural to say "BOY-in-cee", like the first recording. In the second recording, it sounds like she says "BO-yin-cee". However, since the "y" comes right after the "o", it's a very subtle difference. I bet most people would hardly notice a difference unless you put an exaggerated pause between the first two syllables, or if they were listening very closely.

Answer (score 0):

You'll hear both, and I don't think either would be perceived as erroneous by any hearer, regardless of her own pronunciation. I suspect that in most cases the difference wouldn't be perceived at all, as DJ McMayhem's answer suggests.

I suppose if you had a very large corpus of recordings, or had the funds to design and carry out a focused research program, you could determine which pronunciation is more common. But I cannot imagine that it would be worth the effort.